Odoo Save and New Wizard form remember fields data
I need it when adding one2many records in form not in tree.
When you click save & new save the fields and keep some fields not to be cleared to add a new record.
Make one2many modal remember fields
remember [analaytic_account_id,product_id,vendor_id]
class MkVoucher(models.Model):
    _name = 'mk.voucher'

voucher_line_ids = fields.One2many('mk.voucher.line', 'voucher_id', string='Voucher Lines', copy=True)


class MkVoucherLine(models.Model):
    _name = 'mk.voucher.line'
    voucher_id = fields.Many2one('mk.voucher' , string='Voucher')
    product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product',required=True)
    analytic_account_id = fields.Many2one('account.analytic.account', string='Analytic Account',required=True)
    partner_id      = fields.Many2one('res.partner', string='Vendor', required=True,)




product_id = fields.Many2one('product.product', string='Product', required=True, default=lambda self: self._default_product_id())

 @api.model
    def _default_product_id(self):
        latest_line = self.env['mk.voucher.line'].search([], order="id desc", limit=1)
        return latest_line.product_id.id if latest_line else False


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

self.env['mk.voucher.line'].search([], order="id desc", limit=1)
searches in DB , but line not saved in db till the parent voucher saved
